# Is it possible to guess total row count with Angular paginator

Tags: angular, pagination

I'm looking for guidance more than an exact answer. I have an Oracle query that can return over millions of records and it can take more than several seconds to a couple of minutes to build the full result set.  My UI person says he absolutely has to have an exact total number of rows that will be displayed with the paginator.

I believe the paginator is implemented using this
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/paginator

```
<div class="table-view">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <p-table [columns]="selectedColumns1" [value]="invenrotyTab" #dt1 [paginator]="true" [rows]="currPageLimit" exportFilename="Hub Reports Data" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="600px" [resizableColumns]="true" [columnResizeMode]="_columnResizeMode">

            <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
                <div class="ui-helper-clearfix table-controls">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn--small" pButton icon="fa fa-file-o" iconPos="left" label="All Data" (click)="dt1.exportCSV()">Export</button>

                    <div class="left-cont">
                        <p-multiSelect class="hide-columns" [options]="cols1" [(ngModel)]="selectedColumns1" optionLabel="header" selectedItemsLabel="{0} selected" defaultLabel="Choose Columns" (ngModelChange)="onChange()"></p-multiSelect>
                        <input type="text" class="global-search" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Global Filter" (input)="dt1.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" style="width:auto">
                        <p-dropdown class="pagination-container" [options]="pageLimit" [(ngModel)]="currPageLimit" (onClick)="changePageVal()"></p-dropdown>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </ng-template>

            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field" [style]="{'min-width':'100px'}">
                        {{col.header}}
                        <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort" ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order"></p-sortIcon>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
                <tr>
                    <td  class="table-cell-text" *ngFor="let col of columns" [style]="{'min-width':'100px'}">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above is where the pagination template is being used. Not being a strong Angular person, I'm only reasonably confident that the paginator is the one used in the link.

I think a more reasonable thing would be for the paginator to be tolerant of guesses. If the system learns on page 3 that there's at least 5 more, it would be better for it to allow a page update. Or even better, to return something like what nearly all APIs return, which is, getNext() and something to indicate that there is more.

Comment: Is counting the records is overhead? does it take too much time at backend?

Comment: He would probably have to write custom component which will do what you described. This seems like a lot more work that just giving him pageCount or itemCount.

Comment: @Plochie The issue is that the table size is already huge, plus there's a few joins that need to be made. It's possible that a record size count might be slightly smaller, but it would still be expensive.

Comment: For the pagination component of `primeng` you always need the total pages. Which will be calculated by `numeber of records / number of records on single page`.